# Save details to Parse.com as Json

Tags: java, json, parse-platform

I have a small issue understanding how to save data from user input fields to parse.com. I am using the correct methods. However, When I click on my SAVE button nothing is transferred to the server. Do I need to create a separate java class containing the information I am looking to save? What I am doing right now is simply capture the user input, store it in a string and attempt to save those values in parse.com but nothing is happening. I get no errors when attempting to save, but nothing happens anyway. The following is my code. I would really appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class CRUD extends Activity {

//Variables
EditText nameDetail;
EditText emailDetail;
EditText phoneDetail;

String nameField;
String emailField;
String phoneField;


Button save;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.crud);

    nameDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    emailDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    phoneDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // Button onClick Listener
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            nameField = nameDetail.getText().toString();
            emailField = emailDetail.getText().toString();
            phoneField = phoneDetail.getText().toString();

            ParseObject details = new ParseObject("Details");
            details.put("name", nameField);
            details.put("email", emailField);
            details.put("phone", phoneField);
            details.saveInBackground();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have followed the [Quick-start](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) thoroughly but I think you might miss something there, especially the part where you need to initialize parse :

`Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");`

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was using strings to capture numeric values. After correcting the issue for the phone number field the project compiled. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was using strings to capture numeric values. After correcting the issue for the phone number field the project compiled. Thanks for your help anyway